# DirectX 9 engine Z-buffer not working with D3DImage

Tags: c++, wpf, directx, depth-buffer, d3dimage

I am trying to integrate my Direct9 engine into my new WPF application via D3DImage. Everything is working except for the Z buffer. With the AutoDepthStencil at FALSE I can render my meshes but the depth arent working. When I activate the AutoDepthStencil nothing is drawn. Ive been looking around for days and found nothing to help meq

Hers's the presentation parameters

```
ZeroMemory( m_pp, sizeof(m_pp) );

m_pp->AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
m_pp->BackBufferCount            = 1;
m_pp->MultiSampleQuality         = 0;
m_pp->Windowed                   = Windowed;
m_pp->MultiSampleType            = D3DMULTISAMPLE_8_SAMPLES;
m_pp->EnableAutoDepthStencil     = FALSE;
m_pp->PresentationInterval       = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE;
m_pp->Windowed                   = TRUE;
m_pp->BackBufferHeight           = 1;
m_pp->BackBufferWidth            = 1;
m_pp->SwapEffect                 = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
m_pp->BackBufferFormat           = D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8;
```

The renderStates :

```
m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, TRUE);    // turn off the 3D lighting
m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->SetRenderState(D3DRS_AMBIENT, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(50,50,50));
m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SHADEMODE, D3DSHADE_GOURAUD); 
m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DIFFUSEMATERIALSOURCE, D3DMCS_MATERIAL);
m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SPECULARMATERIALSOURCE, D3DMCS_MATERIAL);
m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SPECULARENABLE, TRUE );
m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_CCW);    // both sides of the triangles
m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE);    // turn on the z-buffer
m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->SetRenderState(D3DRS_NORMALIZENORMALS, TRUE);
m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZFUNC, D3DCMP_LESS);
m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZWRITEENABLE, TRUE);
m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->LightEnable( 0, TRUE );
```

Resets:

```
m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET , D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
```

Surface and device creation :

```
if (FAILED(m_pD3D9->CreateDeviceEx(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, m_hWnd,
    dwVertexProcessing,
    m_pp, NULL, GetDevicePtr())))
{
    return NULL;
}

// obtain the standard D3D device interface
if (FAILED(GetDeviceD3D()->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDirect3DDevice9), reinterpret_cast<void **>(GetDevicePtr()))))
{
    return NULL;
}

// create and set the render target surface
// it should be lockable on XP and nonlockable on Vista

if (FAILED(GetDeviceD3D()->CreateRenderTarget(Width, Height, 
    D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DMULTISAMPLE_8_SAMPLES, 0, 
    false, // lockable
    GetSurfacePtr(), NULL)))
{
    return NULL;
}
GetDeviceD3D()->SetRenderTarget(0, m_surface);
```

Matrices:

```
    // set the projection transform
    D3DXMATRIX matProjection;    // the projection transform matrix
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProjection,
                                D3DXToRadian(45),    // the horizontal field of view
                                1.f, // aspect ratio TODO
                                0.001f,    // the near view-plane
                                1000.0f);    // the far view-plane
    m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProjection);     // set the projection

    //CAMERA
    D3DXMATRIX matView;
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
        &D3DXVECTOR3 (m_scene->Cam->Position.X, m_scene->Cam->Position.Y, m_scene->Cam->Position.Z),   // the camera position
        &D3DXVECTOR3 (m_scene->Cam->Target.X, m_scene->Cam->Target.Y, m_scene->Cam->Target.Z),    // the look-at position
        &D3DXVECTOR3 (m_scene->Cam->UpVector.X, m_scene->Cam->UpVector.Y, m_scene->Cam->UpVector.Z));    // the up direction
    d3ddev->m_device->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);    // set the view transform to matView
```

Comment: better to provide a picture.

Comment: Sadly i need 10 rep to do so. You can check my x-post on the gamedev site : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90290/directx9-engine-z-buffer-problem-with-d3dimage

Comment: You have all the steps to use z buffer, the only thing I can guess is that the word/view matrix was incorrect.

Comment: I added the matrices. and I also tried with D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovRH and D3DXMatrixLookAtRH. I also tried a new tutorial for D3DImage from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656716(v=vs.110).aspx where you just copy paste the files and folow the steps. The tutorial works well. But as soon as you add the m_pp->EnableAutoDepthStencil     = TRUE; m_pp->AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16; m_graphics->GetDeviceD3D()->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE); nothing is rendered...  Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Have you tried a different depth buffer format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EnableAutoDepthStencil set to TRUE, make sure CreateRenderTarget uses the same width and height as set in the presentation parameters

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! I changed presentation parameter width/height and used D3DFMT_D24S8 as stencil format and it worked!